# Probability distribution and change of variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable who's PDF is  $f_X(x)$

Suppose $Y=g(X)$, where $g(X)$ is monotonic

Then $f_Y = |\frac{d}{dy}(g^{-1}(y))|* f_X(g^{-1}(y)$

**Example:**

$X - Uniform(0,1)$

$Y = g(X) =+\sqrt X$

Then $f_Y(y) = |\frac{d}{dy}(y^2)|* 1 = 2y$

However, I don't understand how this makes sense. $g$ is a bijection. I don't understand how sampling $Y$ should be any different from sampling $X$. For $X$, all values in $[0,1]$ are equally likely - how can this possibly change for $Y$?

Comment: Do you think the intervals $(0,\frac12)$ and $(\frac12,1)$ are "equally likely" for $Y$?

Comment: Indeed all values for $X$ are equally likely: $P(X=x)=0$ for each $x\in(0,1)$. But that does indeed not change for $Y$. Also  $P(g(X)=y)=0$ for every $y\in (0,1)$. This is true for *any* continuous distribution, so it does not prevent $Y$ to have a distribution that differs from the distribution of $X$.

Comment: @Did Great comment - though makes me feel foolish now, ha.

Comment: The wording ``$g(X)$ is monotonic" is undefined because we do not have ordering on the sample space $\Omega$. Do you mean the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotonic?

Comment: Moreover, the condition that "$g$ is monotonic" is not sufficient to guarantee that $Y$ admits a pdf. For example, define $g(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $g(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$. Then $g$ is a monotone function. However, $Y$ takes value in $\{0,1\}$, so $Y$ cannot have a pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $$P(Y \leq y) = P(\sqrt{X} \leq y)$$
Since $X \sim U(0,1)$ this is the same as, $$P(X \leq y^2)$$
This is the key. Originally $F_X(x) = \int_{0}^{x} 1 \ dx$ was equal to $x$ because every successive interval $\delta x$ was equally likely, i.e $X$ assumed values between $[x_i, x_i+\delta x]$ and $[x_i + \delta x, x_i + 2\delta x]$ with equal likelihood $(\delta x)$. And hence $F_x(x+\delta x) = F_X(x) + \delta x = x + \delta x$.

But this isn't the case with $Y$. Note $(y+\delta y)^{2} \approx y^2 + 2y\delta y$. As you can see the width of the successive intervals $X \in\ [y^2, y^2 + 2y\delta y]$ widens with increasing value of $y$ as fast as $2y$ and since the probability that $X$ lies in this interval depends on the width of the interval hence $F_Y(y)$ scales as $2y$.